# Сделать блок для показа удалённых комментариев липким

Tags: предложение, дизайн, инструменты-модератора

Очень хочется, чтобы модераторский блок слева от сообщения продолжал висеть на экране при прокрутке страницы. Это нужно, чтобы не приходилось скроллить от комментариев под длинным сообщением до этого блока для показа удалённых комментариев.

I'd like moderator block on the left of the post to be sticky when scrolling a page. I need it to click link for viewing deleted comments without scrolling to the top of long post.

[image: скриншот]

Вот стили, которые надо добавить / Here are css-styles to be added:

```
.answer {
  position: relative;
}

.post-issue {
  position: sticky; /* and remove absolute - it shouldn't be a fallback */
  top: 8px;
}

.top-bar._fixed ~ .container .post-issue {
  top: 68px;
}
```

Comment: У @NickVolynkin вроде бы был полезный юзерскрипт для этого блока.

Comment: я смотрю, наши новоиспечённые модераторы успешно осваиваются со своей должностью :)

Comment: @mymedia потому что прежние бездельники и баг репорты не постят.

Comment: @alexolut так это не баг, а фиче-реквест.

Comment: @Suvitruf кстати, да. Qweriy, почему это имеет метку [meta-tag:дефект]? А ... понял ... чтобы можно было потом её снять и таким образом снова поднять вопрос на главную. Ну, ладно тогда.

Comment: @alexolut, разработчики читают вопросы с этой меткой. По той же причине на двух языках.

Comment: @Qwertiy про два языка претензий нет. Но выдавать FR за BR не очень хорошо. Смахивает на некоторое мошенничество. К тому же, с чего Вы решили, что FR разрабы не читают?

Comment: @alexolut а читают? Ладно, убрал.

Comment: @Qwertiy [возможность имеется](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6481356#6481356).