# Как помечать модераторские вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, инструменты-модератора

Есть вопросы, относящиеся к интерфейсу, доступному только модераторам, например:

- [Сделать блок для показа удалённых комментариев липким](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6236/178988)
- [Переставить модераторскую кнопку в конец списка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6238/178988)
- [Количество модераторских тревог не обновляется само](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6331/178988)
- [Не показывать в уведомлениях собственные вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6332/178988)

Надо как-то отделить эти вопросы от остальных. Метка [инструменты-модератора](/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0) для этой цели не подходит, поскольку многие вопорсы с ней содержат последствия, видимые всем пользователям, например:

- [Может ли модератор принять ответ на вопрос за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/167/178988)
- [После восстановления перенесённого вопроса остаётся плашка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6245/178988)
- [appended answer as supplemental](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6317/178988)

Нужен какой-то маркер, отделяющий вопросы первой категории от вопросов второй. По сути, нечто вроде [meta-tag:это-существенно-только-для-модераторов-но-если-вы-любопытный‌​-то-тоже-стоит-загля‌​нуть] :)

Изначально я хотел помечать такие вопросы ромбом перед заголовком вопроса, но на эту тему [возникли разногласия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/6238/revisions). Предлагаю решить судьбу ромба в заголовке и выбрать название подходящей метки.

Голосуем за ответ про ромбик и предлагаем название метки в других ответах.
Внимание: ромб не может быть частью метки!

Comment: [[meta-tag:модераторский-междусобойчик]]?

Comment: [tag:ромбохотелки]?

Answer (score 3):

Вопросы о том, как эти инструменты работают, помечайте меткой [инструменты-модератора](/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0).

> Вопросы об инструментах модерации сайта, доступных только модераторам и/или сотрудникам.

Багрепорты и предложения о доработке этих инструментов задавайте **только на Meta.SE** с меткой [moderator-tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-tools).

> Tools available to ♦ moderators.

Здесь, на Мете Ru.SO, такие вопросы неуместны. Модераторы сайтов сети Stack Exchange в большинстве своем не говорят по-русски и не читают нашу Мету. Вместо них за вопросы голосуют участники, которые не пользуются инструментами и не имеют представления о том, как нужно и как удобно модераторам.

Пример — вопрос «[Переставить модераторскую кнопку в конец списка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6238/181472)». В нем 11 человек проголосовали «за», из них не более двух модераторов — я проголосовал «против», наверняка PashaPash тоже, Qwertiy не мог голосовать, как автор. Кто эти девятеро? Должно ли их решение влиять на интерфейс, которым они не пользуются?

---

Специально для того, чтобы обозначить, что вопрос относится к теме Х, на этом сайте есть метки. Если меток недостаточно для категоризации, нужно завести ещё одну метку. Выносить метку в заголовок нельзя. Почему это правило, работающее для всех 150 сайтов, нужно нарушать на нашем? Мы особенные?

Comment: _"нужно завести ещё одну метку",_ но название этой метки никто предложить не в состоянии?

Comment: _"только на Meta.SE"_ - ничего не мешает сначала обсудить тут. Или по-твоему на metaSE будут голосовать и отвечать только модераторы?

Comment: _"Должно ли их решение влиять на интерфейс, которым они не пользуются?"_ - через год треть из них может выбраться в модераторы :)

Answer (score -2):

## Специальная метка не нужна

### Плюсы

- Вроде нет плюсов?

### Минусы

- Вопросы никак не отличаются от других
- Вопросы невозможно искать

Answer (score -4):

## Использовать ли ♦ перед заголовком вопроса?

*Пожалуйста, проголосуйте более подробно за один из первых трёх комментариев!*

### Плюсы

- Рассматриваемый критерий существеннее других меток и требует более заметного выделения, ромб как раз более заметен по сравнению с метками
- На сайте ромб ассоциируется с модераторами, поэтому знак интуитивно понятен (а если нет, то после пары раз точно станет)

### Минусы

- По наличию ромба невозможно искать вопорсы - на мой взгляд, это критичный минус, и именно из-за него вариант с использованием только ромба в заголовке не подходит - нужна ещё и метка, по которой можно будет находить такие вопросы

---

Лично на мой взгляд, нужны одновременно метка и ромб и вот почему:

- Метка нужна для поиска
- Эта метка среди некрасных по сути является самой важной, но использоваться она будет редко и почти во всех случаях окажется на последнем месте, т. к. метки у вопроса сортируются по их частоте на сайте
- Попросить красную метку мы не можем
- Ромб замечательно выполняет свою роль по нахождению на первом месте по заметности по сравнению с метками

Comment: > Ромб в заголовке вообще не нужен.

Comment: > Ромб в заголовке нужен только если решим не создавать отдельную метку.

Comment: > Ромб в заголовке нужен независимо от наличия метки (он более заметен).